# Global Search configuration

Tags: global-search

I have a custom object that has a Record Name Data Type as Text.
[image]

So when the record is created, the name is generated to be something like: 1234-xxx-00000555.
When conducting a Global Search I see results when I type in **1234** or **xxx** or **00000555**. I get no results when searching for just **555**, **0555**, **00555**, etc.

With other custom objects where I have Data Type = to Auto Number
[image]

with a name like OO-00000456, I can just search for **456** and get results. Again I get no results for **0456**, **00456**, **000456**, etc.

My requirement is to be able to search any part of the custom object name and see some results.

Is there a way to configure Global Search to achieve this?

Comment: If "MS Name" is text, then values are not generated but must be specifically set for the `Name` on the record. If you don't, the record's name is the record's ID as a string. As to global search, this uses SOSL (you can learn more [on trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_sosl)). SOSL cannot do suffix matching, only prefix matching. One option you have here is to make sure the name auto-number format only has a single digit, like `OO-{0}`, so you will get values like OO-1, OO-10, OO-100, OO-1000 etc. - i.e. no prefixing 0s.

Comment: @PhilW - Trying to understand. When a MS record is created, its name is generated from the OO record in code so it inherits the number portion of OO's Auto Number record name.  Are you saying that there isn't a way to configure Global Search so that it searches for portions of the name if it is Text and not Auto Number? ie. I can only search for each segment separated by a hyphen? 

OO works for 456 but 555 won't ever work for the MS record? I would have to put in the full number portion - 00000555? 

I don't think reformatting the name is in the cards as a solution, unfortunately.

Comment: When indexing field values for SOSL use, Salesforce splits those values into "words" (around spaces and symbols) and indexes those words. Those words can only be prefix matched. I suspect an auto-number Name is somehow backed by an underlying numeric value that SOSL can use directly, so you are able to find values even with leading zeros. However, when you have any explicit string value that is indexed for SOSL you can then only do whole word or word prefix matches. Thus you can search for "012345" and find it with "01*" or "012345" but not "2345". You can't use a prefix wildcard either.

Comment: Since this is global search you can't even get in and fudge it for yourself by searching for both "*nnn*" and "0\**nnn*" (where nnn is the set of numbers you care about).

Comment: Basically, you cannot do what you want.